# Mootools Jsonp not updating variables

Tags: javascript, mootools, jsonp

I have a global variable called sections.

However, on a certain onclick event, i want to grab those sections via Jsonp and update them.

So my come looks something like this:

```
var sections = [bla];

new Request.JSONP({
    url: 'someurl',
    onComplete: function(theData){
    sections = theData;
    doStuff();
    }
}).send();  

var doStuff = function(){
  console.log(sections);
}
```

But if i run that, i get that sections is still equal to [bla] and not [foo] which the json data should be.

Why is that?

Comment: There's no reason why this shouldn't work as expected. Please set up a jsfiddle.net with the example code.

Comment: is theData actually set? `console.log(theData)` as expected? within onComplete, `console.log(sections)` before the assignment ([bla] ?) any other mention of sections in your scope chain, function definitions etc?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, looks like i was redefining the variable later on which caused the problem.